# JavaScript is Not Working in any of my Browsers

Tags: javascript

I am just learning JavaScript and for some reason this simple (Example 1 from [Chapter One](http://javascriptbook.com/code/c01/)) example is not working (Jon Duckett's JavaScript and Jquery book) in any of my browsers: FireFox, IE, and Chrome.  I made sure JavaScript is turned on.  I also put noscript tags in my index.html file to make sure I had JavaScript on.  My jsFiddle works perfectly, but nothing in my browsers.  Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdaLssrk/) with everything I have in my Atom editor.  My links are correct because I copied the full path and then pasted it into the src.  I then deleted all the C:\users....... until I got into the folder with all of the files to end up with what is in the jsFiddle.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="etf-8" />
<title>Greeting JavaScript</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="scripts/greeting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>Your Browser Does Not Support JavaScript.  Please Enable It.</noscript>
<section>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Constructive &amp; Co.</h1>
</div>
<h3 id="greeting"></h3>
<p>For all orders and inquiries please call <em>555-3344</em></p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;

if (hourNow > 18) {
 greeting = 'Good evening!';
} else if (hourNow > 12) {
 greeting = 'Good afternoon!';
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
 greeting = 'Good morning!';
} else {
 greeting = 'Welcome!';
}

document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = greeting;
```

css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800italic);

body {
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
/*background: url("../images/constructive-backdrop.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;*/
background: #a18957;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
section {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
height: 500px;
width: 400px;
background: #eee;
border: 1px solid #292929;
}
#header {
height: 200px;
margin: 10px;
background: rgba(227, 192, 186, 0.78);
}
h1 {
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 45%;
}
h3 {
height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
background: red;
}
p {
margin: 10px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Even if you make a fiddle, you should post the code here (where it's perfectly easy to read).

Comment: JSFiddle runs in your browser, so javascript is working in your browser.....

Comment: You misspelled "script" as "scipt" in the html head.

Comment: Based on your example, #Matt has a point : <scipt src="scripts/greeting.js"></scipt>

Comment: I just changed the "scipt" to "script" and still nothing for some reason

Comment: I also suggest that you read about debugging javascript - using the developer tools breakpoints or console.log can help you figure out exactly what isn't going the way you expect it to - it really makes debugging so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the `script` tag at the end of your html. The element `greeting` doesn't exist, when you are executing it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Greeting JavaScript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>Your Browser Does Not Support JavaScript.  Please Enable It.</noscript>
  <section>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Constructive &amp; Co.</h1>
    </div>
    <h3 id="greeting"></h3>
    <p>For all orders and inquiries please call <em>555-3344</em></p>
  </section>
  <script src="scripts/greeting.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you leave it in the head and wrap the script into

```
addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {

    var today = new Date();
    var hourNow = today.getHours();
    var greeting;

    if (hourNow > 18) {
      greeting = 'Good evening!';
    } else if (hourNow > 12) {
      greeting = 'Good afternoon!';
    } else if (hourNow > 0) {
      greeting = 'Good morning!';
    } else {
      greeting = 'Welcome!';
    }

    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = greeting;

  }
}, false);
```

It is wonderful you use `document.getElementById`, instead of `document.write`!

Comment: This did it!  Thanks you very much mate!  Do you know why this happens when placing the script in the head?

Comment: It's because the element doesn't exist when the script is executed. You could wrap the script into `addEventListener("readystatechange", function () { if (document.readyState === "interactive") { /**/ } }, false);` to run it when parsing is finished. (see the `/**/`)

Comment: It took me awhile to see what you were saying, but I think I get it now.  The script is executed before the HTML is even loaded, so placing the script at the bottom allows the html to load and then the script to load.  thanks for the help